# YouTube video recommendations

Tags: youtube

How does YouTube know what to recommend to me even when I am not logged into my Google account?  It seems weird that even when I am not signed into my Google account YouTube is still recommending the right videos?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube can track you using your IP address and by the cookies they store in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube recommends videos based on what is trending in your region and videos you have previously searched/watched based on cookies saved in your system.